# Randomly placing list items into parts of a string

Tags: python, list, random

I have three lists `Main`, `Supplemental` and `Auxiliary`, all containing several strings.

I'm trying to generate a new string from a combination of random elements of these. `Main` will have a defined index, but the others indices should be chosen randomly. The order that these come out should be random too.

This is what will get the job done:

```
main = main[5]
supp = random.choice(supplemental)
aux = random.choice(auxiliary)

all = [main, supp, aux]

print(random.choice(all) + random.choice(all) + random.choice(all))
```

However, this isn't particularly elegant and poses a high chance of collision.

Is there a better way to think about this, and one that won't cause the same to list to be picked?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle) your items:

```
>>> import random
>>> all_ = ['a', 'b', 'c']   # I use explicit strings instead of your [main, supp, aux]
>>> random.shuffle(all_)
>>> print(''.join(all_))
cba
>>> print(''.join(all_))
bac
```

With `shuffle` there won't be collisions except if your list contains duplicate items.

[`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample) could also be used if you don't want the extra shuffle step. It doesn't change the original list either and also works if the input contains more than 3 items and you only want 3:

```
>>> print(''.join(random.sample(all_, 3)))
bca
```

Comment: `random.sample(all_, 3)` will save you the shuffling. Also, I doubt that the second `print` yielded a different output without shuffling first ;)